# jQuery $(document).ready is not a function - Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-selectors, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am relatively new to rails and recently upgraded my rails 3.0 application to rails 3.1. Things seem to be working fine, however when I started coding some jquery in my application, i am unable to call most of jquery methods. For example, I have a div:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  here is some content here
</div>
```

When I call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myDiv").hide();
})
```

My browser throws the error

```
$(document).ready is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1:11
```

Something to note, when I write the js without $(document).ready() underneath the div like this

```
<div id="myDiv">
    here is some content
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("#myDiv").hide();
</script>
```

my browser throws the error

```
$("#myDiv") is null @ http://localhost:3000/:57
```

Here is the interesting part. When I remove the # and write it like

```
$("myDiv").hide();
```

It WORKS!! No errors. Why? I don't know. But when I change it to $("myDiv").addClass("anotherClass"); or anything fancy, i get the error again

```
$("myDiv").addClass is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/:57
```

I have no other javascript errors. Any idea why this would be happening? How can I fix this?

I already have `gem 'jquery-rails'` added in my gem file.

Here is my application.js file

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults

// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file. // require_tree 
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require prototype
//= require bootstrap-alerts-1.3.0
//= require bootstrap-dropdown-1.3.0
//= require bootstrap-modal-1.3.0
//= require bootstrap-twipsy-1.3.0
//= require bootstrap-popover-1.3.0
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy-1.3.0
//= require bootstrap-tabs-1.3.0

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myDiv").hide();
})
```

I tried removing all the bootstrap js files btw, had no affect. It is clearly loading jQuery.

Any clues on how to get jQuery working normally?

Comment: are you sure that the script tag including jquery appears in the final markup, prior to you using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're intentionally using both jquery and prototype you'll need to noConflict one of them; you're loading prototype after jQuery, so redefining the $ function.

Comment: ah! thanks for the quick response. I just removed Prototype and that fixed it.. I have no idea why that line was there!

Comment: @alik Magic! Happens all the time :)

Comment: just to someone who might search and get here, if noConflict is enabled on jQuery, you have to change every $ to jQuery, so jQuery(document).ready(...